# ROS serial communication error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

While trying again to connect arduino with ROS, I got the following error

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1479016828.422284] Protocol version of client is unrecognized, expected Rev 1 (rosserial 0.5+)
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1479016830.422676] Mismatched protocol version in packet: lost sync or rosserial_python is from different ros release than the rosserial client
[INFO] [WallTime: 1479016830.424668] Protocol version of client is unrecognized, expected Rev 1 (rosserial 0.5+)
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1479016837.411422] Lost sync with device, restarting...
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1479016852.414668] Lost sync with device, restarting...
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1479016867.417601] Lost sync with device, restarting...
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247965/ros-serial-communication-error/) by [marwa eldiwiny](https://answers.ros.org/users/27638/marwa-eldiwiny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2016-11-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-13**:
Could I please ask you to use the *Preformatted Text* button when copying console text into your question (it's the one with `101010` on it)? That will make it much easier to read.

Thank you.

**Comment by [marwa eldiwiny](https://answers.ros.org/users/27638/marwa-eldiwiny/) on 2016-11-14**:
rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py _port:= /dev/ttyACM0

Here is the error I got, while for the first time, it was working perfectly. BTW, hello example in ros_lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1479116767.531493] Mismatched protocol version in packet: lost sync or rosserial_python is from different ros release than the rosserial client
[INFO] [WallTime: 1479116767.535425] Protocol version of client is unrecognized, expected Rev 1 (rosserial 0.5+)
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1479116774.520920] Lost sync with device, restarting...
rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py _port:= /dev/ttyACM0[ERROR] [WallTime: 1479116789.534359] Lost sync with device, restarting...
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1479116804.537555] Lost sync with device, restarting...
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1479116819.540783] Lost sync with device, restarting...
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1479116834.544034] Lost sync with device, restarting...
[ERROR] [Wal
```

---

Originally posted by [marwa eldiwiny](https://answers.ros.org/users/27638/marwa-eldiwiny/) with karma: 51 on 2016-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marwa eldiwiny](https://answers.ros.org/users/27638/marwa-eldiwiny/) on 2016-11-14**:
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1479116767.531493] Mismatched protocol version in packet: lost sync or rosserial_python is from different ros release than the rosserial client
[INFO] [WallTime: 1479116767.535425] Protocol version of client is unrecognized, expected Rev 1 (rosserial 0.5+)
[ERROR] [WallTime: 14791